# 1080p video can't play in VLC

Tags: 20.04, video, vlc, video-player

I was first a Windows user, but recently switched to Ubuntu.

I want to play 1080p .`mkv` videos on VLC but it won't play properly. In Windows it works but not in Ubuntu.

VLC was my default player, but now I like Ubuntu video player a lot. My screen resolution is 1366×768.

How do I get 1080p video to play on on VLC?

Comment: What is your video card? Please add the following output to your question `lspci -knn | grep -A3 -Ei "video|vga|3d"` . Then run `sudo apt-get install vainfo` and share output of `vainfo` .

Answer (score 0):

Try another video player like `Kaffeine`, `MPV` or `SMPlayer`. Are you able to play any other video? It may be related to your graphics drivers but we don't know.

Does it display a black window or the player just closes immediately?

Comment: i am able to play the same file in ubuntu videos player but that file wont play in vlc. will try the players you suggested. yes it display black window only audio plays. i have changes the setting suggested from youtube but  i didnt work.

Comment: have you installed the codecs? `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: yes i have installed restricted extras

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the codecs for videos to play properly. They aren't loaded by default.

In a terminal enter:
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: yes i have installed restricted extras